# how to disable dimming selection colors after some delay in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I set custom colors in settings.json

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "editor.selectionBackground": "#047692",
        "editor.selectionHighlightBackground": "#9044aa",
```

but vscode keeps dimming / overwriting custom colors after a delay after selecting a word (or double clicking) as in this gif (especially at the end):

[image]

how to disable this behavior? So only my colors are shown

Comment: Not a programming question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don't see colors dimming in the gif, are you talking about semantic highlighting, that lags behind syntax highlighting

Comment: @rioV8 yes, probably semantic highlaighting that lags behind, in the gif one color is selected and then very fast it changes to a less saturated color (clearly visible at the and where "area2D" variable is highlighted). I already solved that (disabled Occurrences Highlight) but need 2 days to select my own answer as a solution

Comment: Not a programming question you say, but the use of the tag "visual-studio-code" is officially endorsed, did you know? If you say so, give us what places we can ask "questions" about vscode aside from here SO and github issues, please?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED. Disabled option

```
Editor: Occurrences Highlight
```